# How to sort arrays of different datatypes

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort candidate names alphabetically while sorting votes gained by candidate,I took two arrays one for names and another for votes,as i sort by votes name array need to sort here i can't make it sort please help
here is my code:

```
package com.sarga.Swinglearn;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project3 {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    int i=0,j=0;
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of candidates");
    int candcount = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Enter name of the candiadates");
    String names[]=new String[candcount];//create an array
    for( i=0;i<names.length;i++)
    {
        names[i]=s.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("candidates are: ");
    for(i=0;i<candcount;i++)
        System.out.println(names[i]);
    for(i=0;i<candcount;i++)
    {
        for(j=i;j<candcount;j++)
        {
            if(names[i].compareTo(names[j])>0)
            {
                String temp=names[i];
                names[i]=names[j];
                names[j]=temp;  
            }
        }   
    }
    /*To sort names alphabetically*/
    System.out.println("alphabetical order of candidates");
    for(i=0;i<candcount;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(names[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("Enter number of votes of each candidate");
     int votes[]=new int[candcount];
    for(i=0;i<candcount;i++)
    {
         votes[i]=s.nextInt();
        System.out.println(names[i]+":"+votes[i]);
    }
    //sort names based on their votes
    System.out.println("List of candidates according to their votes");
    //int max= votes[1];
    int temp=0;
    for(i=0;i<candcount-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=i;j<candcount;j++)
        {
            if(votes[i]<votes[j])
            {
             temp=votes[i];
             votes[i]=votes[j];
             votes[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<candcount;i++)
    System.out.println(names[i]+":"+votes[i]);
    s.close();
}

}
```

Comment: I suggest you create a class that holds name and vote-count. Then you can make an array of that type and when sorting by vote-count, you'll get the correct order of the names. Btw: There is [Sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-) in the Arrays-Class

Comment: Create a new Object to encapsulate name and votes and store in `ArrayList` and use `Collections.sort` with custom comparator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shoul use object oriented paradigm ; create a `Candidate` class which implements the Comparable interface :

```
public class Candidate
    implements Comparable<Candidate>
{
    public String name; /* should use getter and setter */
    public int votes; /* idem */

    public int compareTo(Candidate other)
    {
         /* implements the comparison, see Comparable doc */
    }
}
```

Then sort a Candidate array in your main :

```
Candidate[] candidates = new Candidate[candcount];
/* populates the array */
Arrays.sort(candidates);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Candidate` class:

```
public class Candidate implements Comparable<Candidate> {
    private String name;
    private int votes;

    public Candidate(String name, int votes) {
        this.name = Objects.requireNotNull(name);
        this.votes = votes;
    }

    // Getters and setters

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Candidate that) {
        int c = this.name.compareTo(that.name);
        if(c != 0) return c;
        return this.votes - that.votes;
    }
}
```

Next create a list of those candidates and sort them:

```
List<Candidate> clist = new ArrayList<>();
// Add some Candidates to clist
Collections.sort(clist);
```